# Not Rooted Huawei Device, Android 4.4.4, Locked Out. USB debugging not enabled One is huawei. h60 -L01 Second is CHM-U01

Tags: root-access, data-recovery, locked-out

Thanks for your time. I have a huawei phone which isn't rooted and USB debugging isn't enabled. Furthermore, I am locked out. Please suggest any remedy. I have searched out the whole internet but there isn't any solution, as far as I know. 
And if there is No possibility please suggest me how to access my data by any mean. Even if it's post hard-reset recovery.
Please Help!
Thanks!

Edit 1: 
Actually I handed over 2 phones to my employees. They gave me a loss of 42000$ and I have recovered 2 phones from them. I didn’t recover any cash but these two phones which can give me a lead to what they were actually up to. As I am from Pakistan, I don’t want to go into any legal process. So, that’s what I am looking for and I can spend money even to recover the data inside. –

So you can say I am not the owner but I would have asked it directly than it would be giving an outlook that I am a thief lol. So.... I am in a great need of the data inside that phone. Any sort of help that can give me access to full data will be highly appreciated. And I am willing to pay for that even. –

And thanks for staying there and spending the time to read all that long passages. Thanks again! –

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want

Comment: We can't help you if we don't actually know the issue

Comment: I am describing that the phones are locked that’s the whole issue. I am the owner of the phones and I gave them to my employees. They cheated me and gave me a set back of 48000$. I want to unlock the phone and read all the data inside. To get to know what they were up to!

Comment: Phones are locked. The google account inside one of the phone was mine. I locked it and now I can’t unlock it because I don’t know the passcode or pattern.

Comment: set a temporary screen lock password from google account, then unlock with this temporary password

Comment: the Honor 4C and 6 both have "backup user data" in recovery mode. once you have backup, come back here https://www.hardreset.info/devices/huawei/huawei-honor-4c/recovery-mode

Comment: @AbdullahAliAbbasi have you checked the backups? can you extract it? then you can unlock bootloader and restore the modified backups, ask here if you still need help

Comment: No Alecxs I cant create a backup as there is no backup otion and bootloader is locked.

Answer (score 1):

Huawei has locked bootloader by default, no chance to boot custom recovery from fastboot = no way to break in and reset locksettings.db
(you can check the unlock status with `fastboot oem device-info`)

If you are the owner of the bonded google account and phone, you can connect it over wifi, or insert a SIM card (with disabled PIN) to accomplish mobile data connection. if you recently changed your Google account password, you need to wait at least 72 hours.

**Unlock your Kitkat Android device**

- After you've tried to unlock your device multiple times, you'll see "Forgot pattern."
- Tap Forgot pattern.
- Enter the Google Account username and password
- Reset your screen lock

**Unlock your Android device using Android Device Manager (ADM)**

- On a computer, visit: google.com/android/devicemanager
- Sign in using your Google login details
- In the ADM interface, select the device
- Select ‘Lock’
- In the appearing window, enter a temporary password. You don’t have to enter a recovery message.
- Now click ‘Lock’ again.
- If it was successful, you should see a confirmation below the box with the buttons Ring, Lock and Erase.
- On your phone you should now see a password field in which you should enter the temporary password. This should unlock your phone.
- Now, before you go on with your life, go to your phone’s lock screen settings and disable the temporary password.

**Android system recovery <3e> userdata_20160823_100259.backup**

If your device has slot for external MicroSD Card or USB-OTG Support, is not encrypted, and has "backup user data" option enabled by default, you can create a backup from stock recovery. This backup files can be extracted with linux tools (google: "bckp2win")

**Brute forcing a 4-digit PIN**

If you are not the owner of the google account, the only way will be to bruteforce a 4 digit PIN with a Hak5 USB Rubber Ducky or Teensy microcontroller via USB-OTG Adapter. if it is a longer PIN or password, no chance!

Comment: source: https://trendblog.net/how-to-bypass-android-phone-lock-screen-pattern-pin-password

Comment: One is huawei  h60 -L01 Second is CHM-U01

Comment: Nice answer @alecxs you cover most of methods that will work but need to execute them correctly.

Comment: there are more methods, but these are the easiest one. I recommend to check recovery mode and bootloader mode first. I will update other methods if we can be sure that backup functionality is not available and bootloader is locked